# Box2Dlights Shadows not working

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I’ve just implemented Box2DLights in my LibGDX game. It works otherwise fine but after I added static bodies they don’t cast shadows.

[image: As you can see, the wall doesn’t cast a shadow]

Wall does however multiply point light somehow.

[image: It even multiply point light somehow]

Here are the parts of my code where I am using Box2D and Box2Dlights:

```java
Vector2 gravity = new Vector2(0,0);
debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
world = new World(gravity, false);

rayHandler = new RayHandler(world);
rayHandler.setCombinedMatrix(camera.combined);
rayHandler.setShadows(true);

// This adds wall tiles from TiledMap into obstacles and to box2d world         
for (MapObject wall : mapObjects) {                                             
    RectangleMapObject rmo = (RectangleMapObject) wall;                         

    if (rmo.getName() == null || !rmo.getName().contentEquals("window")) {      
        Rectangle rec = rmo.getRectangle();                                     


        obstacles.add(rec);                                                     
        rec.set(rec.x / 128 - mapRec.x, rec.y / 128 - mapRec.y,                 
                rec.width / 128, rec.height / 128);                             

        BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();                                        
        bodyDef.type = BodyType.StaticBody;                                     
        bodyDef.position.set(rec.getX()+rec.width/2,rec.getY()+rec.height/2);  

        Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);                                  

        PolygonShape groundBox = new PolygonShape();                            

        groundBox.setAsBox(rec.width/2,rec.height/2);                           

        body.createFixture(groundBox, 1.0f);                                    

        groundBox.dispose();                                                    
    }                                                                           
}                                       

//The point light and the cone light;                                                                                                                              
pointLight= new PointLight(rayHandler, 100, new Color(1,1,1,0.5f), 0.5f, myCharacter.getAdjustedPosX(), myCharacter.getAdjustedPosY());                            
coneLight = new ConeLight(rayHandler, 100, new Color(1,1,1,0.5f), 3, myCharacter.getAdjustedPosX(), myCharacter.getAdjustedPosY(), myCharacter.getRotation(), 30f);
```

And the render part:

```java
// After I have rendered walls sprites etc.                                                                                     
world.step(1/60f, 6, 2);                                                                                                        
rayHandler.setCombinedMatrix(camera.combined, camera.position.x, camera.position.y,camera.viewportWidth, camera.viewportHeight);
rayHandler.updateAndRender();                                                                                                   
debugRenderer.render(this.world, camera.combined);
```

I have tried things from numerous tutorials and examples, for example I added the world.step(), but they haven’t changed a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shadows started working after I set softness length to zero.

```java
pointLight.setSoftnessLength(0);
coneLight.setSoftnessLength(0);
```